# UIViewController occasionally black

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController with a ContainerView (connected to a blank UIView) and a table. Sometimes it displays correctly (I load JSON data in viewDidLoad), but other times the whole view is black. I tried to pinpoint it to a certain layout change, so I reversed the changes (view displayed correctly again) and then redid the changes exactly as before (view still displayed correctly).

There is no crash, nor any error message when the view is black. The program still seems to run in the background, I can switch to other parts with the TabBar.

The only indication in code that something went wrong is, that

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

is never called. But if the TableView fails, why is the whole ViewController not displayed?

[image]

Edit: Code for viewdidload.

```
    let tURL = NSURL(string: "<urlofjsonfile>")
    var JSONData:NSData? = nil
    do {
        JSONData = try NSData(contentsOfURL: tURL!, options: [])
    } catch {
        print("\(error)")
    }
    if let json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData!, options: [])) as? NSDictionary {
        if let serienstartJsonArray = json["sendungen"] as? [NSDictionary] {
            for item in serienstartJsonArray {
                let meldung=SerienDataModel(json: item)
                seriendaten.append(meldung)
            }
            arrSectionStart.append(0)
            if let id = json["anzahl1"] as? Int {
                arrSectionRows.append(id+1)
            } else {
                arrSectionRows.append(0)
            }
            if let numb2 = json["anzahl2"] as? Int {
                arrSectionStart.append(arrSectionRows[0]+1)
                arrSectionRows.append(numb2)
            } else {
                arrSectionRows.append(0)
                arrSectionStart.append(1)
            }
            arrSectionStart.append(arrSectionRows[0]+arrSectionRows[1]+3)
            if let numb3 = json["anzahl3"] as? Int {
                arrSectionRows.append(numb3)
            } else {
                arrSectionRows.append(0)
            }

        } else {
            print("Error creating dictionary")
        }
    } else {
        print("Error NSJSONSerialization")
    }
```

Comment: can you show the code for viewDidload

Comment: is the background color of your tableview black?

Comment: No, the background is transparent and the view's background color is light blue.

Answer (score 0):

You are networking synchronously in `viewDidLoad`:

```
JSONData = try NSData(contentsOfURL: tURL!, options: [])
```

Never never never do that. Do not network synchronously except on a background thread. Network properly (asynchronously) and update your model and interface afterwards on the main thread.

Comment: You are right - but even if I disable the whole networking code (essentially creating an empty table), the view is still black. It also doesn't explain why the whole view is black instead of just the table view...